# Three UIButton inside a vertical stack view. Click first button also triggers the last button

Tags: ios, uibutton, uistackview

Here is an example project that describes the issue:

https://github.com/nuynait/UIStackView-UIButton-Bug

Here is a one min video for creating the bug: [Click here](https://s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/share.tshan.me/ios-bug/stackview+bug+screencast.mov)

To reproduce this issue:

1. Create a new single app project
2. Click on story board
3. Add a vertical stack view
4. Add top, bottom, leading, trailing constraint for stackview to its parent.
5. Set vertical stack view to fill equaily (This is an optional step)
6. Add a button into the stack view
7. Add another button into the stack view
8. Add a third button into the stack view (This is also optional step)
9. Run the app in the simulator.
10. Click on the first button.

Expected behavior: Only the first button should be highlighted when pressed down on the first button.

Actual behavior: The first and third button all highlighted when pressed down on the first button only.

Update: I am using Xcode 11.3 (11C29), The iPhone 8 Simulator (iOS 13.3)

Comment: Hmmm... grabbed your GitHub repo... also followed your video to create from scratch... I do ***not*** see the same thing you're getting. Each button highlights independently, as expected. I'm using Xcode 11.2.1 and ran it on iPhone 8 / iOS 13.2.2 simulator, and on iPhone XR / iOS 13.3.1

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for checking for me. After knowing that it's good for you, I tried to restart the Xcode, simulators and also restart the computer and this problem no longer exists anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This problem no longer happens on me. If you also experience this issue:

Try following to see if it fixed:

1. restart the Xcode
2. restart the simulators
3. restart computer
4. try running it on a real device.
5. update the Xcode version if possible.

---

OLD ANSWER:

*I guess its a bug from Apple. I have submitted a bug report to Apple. For now, if you are experiencing this issue and want a temporary solution, the solution I have is to add a UIView below the StackView for 1px height. In that case, it will not trigger the last button when you click the first button anymore.*

[image]

*Please note that the fake view has to be visible and at least 1 pixel on height It cannot be set as hidden or 0 on alpha.*